# Error opening 2.1.0-M01 database in Neo4j 2.1.2

Tags: neo4j

I've upgraded to Neo4j 2.1.2 and I'm trying to open databases created in 2.1.0-M01.

When I try to start Neo4j 2.1.2 with a database that was working and still is in 2.1.0-M01 on a separate computer, I get this error:

Starting Neo4j Server failed: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, C:\Users\xxxxxxx\Documents\Neo4j\analytics.graphdb

I tried uncommenting allow_store_upgrade=true in neo4j.properties in the database folder, but this did not help.

The error occurs for two separate databases that are both working in 2.1.0-M01.

I'm not sure where the EmbeddedGraphDatabase part of the error message is coming from.  I'm not using an embedded version.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had performed a clean shutdown of the databases in M01.

When trying to load the M01 database, Neo4j never even got to the point that it was putting anything in messages.log.  No help there.

Really hard to believe that an M01 version database is incompatible with the next version.  Oh well, lesson learned the (somewhat) hard way.

I just went back to M01, loaded the old databases and exported the entire contents to Cypher.  Then created new databases in 2.1.2 and imported the old database contents.  A little painful, but at least possible.

Answer (score 0):

Check `data/graph.db/messages.log` for warnings and errors. Always make sure that you did a clean shutdown with the old version prior to upgrading.

In general there is no guarantee for upgrades between milestones. Milestones are intended to collect feedback from users and not for production purposes.